# fail to start the customization toolbox in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: linux, websphere, websphere-8

I installed the websphere 8.5 supplements on linux Redhat.
and when I finish i select to start the customization tool box but nothing appeared so I execute the command

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT/wct.sh

but I got an error

./wct.sh: ./eclipse: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Do you guys have any idea ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing some libraries. If you are on 64bit platform ensure that required libraries are in both version 32 and 64 bit versions.

See also:

- [Preparing Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 for installation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tins_linuxsetup_rhel6.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en)
- [Unable to install Installation Manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21459143)

Comment: Thanks for the info I had the same issues. The links you posted were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I was installing the WCT on RHEL7.2. I got the issue while starting the wst.sh script. The Problem was the package dependencies specially the compat-libstdc++ which is not available by default in the packages of RHEL7 iso repo(We got repo from my company, so perhaps they removed this package from list.). Anyways, I took the package from RHEL6 ISO and install it using rpm. Also I needed to install.
compat-db-4.6.21-15
libstdc++-4.4.4-13
libXp-1.0.0-15.1
libXmu-1.0.5-1
libXtst-1.0.99.2-3
pam-1.1.1-4
libXft-2.1.13-4.1
gtk2-2.18.9-4
gtk2-engines-2.18.4-5

I did un-installation of WCT and re-install it. It works like a charm after that.
I hope it helps you or others.